# Download many files to app

Tags: android, ios, download, zip

We have an app where we are downloading some texts and up to three hundred images when the user log into the app. The app is initially downloaded from App Store or Google Play and the download from the stores is working fine.

We are however experiencing quite slow download times for the images. E.g. it will take up to 8 minutes to download about 250 images with a resolution of 768*1024. When we download a single file of a comparable size (to the 250 images), that download can be achieved in about 1 minute. We have investigated a bit and found an overhead of about 150 ms pr file, but this does not nearly explain the difference between downloading the same volume in one file vs 250 files, so we are not sure where the remaining overhead is coming from.

We are now considering to zip all the images on server before download and then unzip images on the app. There will be some overhead on packing and unpacking of the zip file, but it might be worthwhile.

Does anybody have experience with this kind of packing/unpacking architecture for downloading many files on to apps, or maybe other suggestions for increasing the performance of the download?

Thanks.

Claus

Comment: how are you downloading the images?

Comment: Through a webservice

Comment: but how are you *downloading* them?

Answer (score 0):

You're probably establishing seperate connections for each file download, which causes a lot of TCP overhead, especially if the connection is secure, which it should be.

You should persist one connection and use that to transfer all files.

Comment: First of all: yes we are using a secure connection. However we are downloading all the images at the time the user logs into the app. I would think the connection is kept open during this download time because there is continous activity. But it seems you think the connection is closed between each image download. If that is the case, what is your suggestion for keeping the connection persistently open?

Comment: I think our solution will be to make a .tar version of the images so we can get all files in one go. Then we do no have overhead from all those small files. For Android I think we will use the download manager to control the download of the big file, and for iOS it will be either background transfer service or keeping the app from going to background by using: UIApplication.sharedApplication().idleTimerDisabled = true